# Bind variables to combobox and textbox in Powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, user-interface

I'm coming with more problems to you.

I've built a simple GUI to create a printer or change the driver on a print server. However, when I click the button RUN, it does not make anything just only pops up the message that the operation was successful. May somebody help me checking the code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#region pop up the gui

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

[xml]$xaml = @"
    <Window
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="Print Queue Configuration Tool" Height="800" Width="800" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Topmost="True">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,85,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Welcome to Print Queue Configuration Tool" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Margin="537,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" Source="logo.png"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,140,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="What do you want to do?" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.422,0.157" Height="31" Width="257" FontSize="16"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="RadioCreate" Content="Create a print queue." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,194,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="RadioChange" Content="Change driver to a print queue." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,194,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboMaker" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="460,260,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Dascom"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="HP"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Kyocera"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Lexmark"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Zebra"/>
            </ComboBox>
            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboModel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="460,310,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290">
            </ComboBox>
            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboTray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="460,360,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290">
            </ComboBox>
            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboDriver" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="460,410,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290">
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxPQ" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="460,460,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290" SelectionOpacity="4"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxServer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="460,510,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxHostname" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="460,560,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxLocation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="460,610,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,260,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select the maker:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="304" Height="22" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,310,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select the model:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="304" Height="22" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,360,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select the no. of additional trays (only for model CX825, CX921, CX922, MX910, X950):" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="304" Height="32" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,410,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select the driver:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="304" Height="22" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,460,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Add the print queue name:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="304" Height="22" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,510,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Add the server name:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="304" Height="22" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,560,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Add the hostname:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="304" Height="22" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,610,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Add the location (i.e. DE-Eltmann):" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="304" Height="22" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button x:Name="ButtonRun" Content="Run" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="660,710,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Height="35"/>

        </Grid>
    </Window>
"@  
    
    #Read XAML 
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

    #Add actions to button Run
$RadioCreate = $window.FindName("RadioCreate")


$RadioChange = $window.FindName("RadioChange")


$ComboMaker = $window.FindName("ComboMaker")
$ComboModel = $window.FindName("ComboModel")
$ComboDriver = $window.FindName("ComboDriver")
$ComboMaker.Add_DropdownClosed({
    $ComboModel.Items.Clear()
    $ComboDriver.Items.Clear()

    switch ($ComboMaker.Text) {
        "Dascom" {
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Dascom T2150s")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Dascom T2380")
        }
        "HP" {
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("HP LaserJet M507dn")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("HP LaserJet M700 M712dn")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("HP Color LaserJet M553dn")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("HP OfficeJet Pro 8210")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("HP PageWide Pro 452dw")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("HP PageWide Enterprise Color 556dn")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("HP DesignJet T1600")
        }
        "Kyocera" {
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Kyocera P3155dn")
        }
        "Lexmark" {
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Lexmark CX625adhe")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Lexmark CX825dte")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Lexmark CX921de")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Lexmark CX922de")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Lexmark MX722adhe")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Lexmark MS725dvn")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Lexmark MX910de")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Lexmark X950de")
        }
        "Zebra" {
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Zebra ZD620t 300 dpi")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Zebra ZT620 300 dpi")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Zebra 220Xi4 300 dpi")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Zebra ZT610-300 dpi")
            $ComboModel.Items.Add("Zebra ZQ630 Mobile Printer")
        }
    }
    switch ($ComboMaker.Text) {
        "Dascom" {
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("Tally T2150_")
        }
        "HP" {
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("HP DesignJet HPGL2 Driver")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("HP Designjet T790ps 44in PS3")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("HP DesignJet T930 HPGL2")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("HP DesignJet Universal Print Driver HPGL2")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("HP DesignJet Universal Print Driver HPGL2(v4.5.0)")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("HP Universal Printing PS")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("HP Universal Printing PS (v6.3.0)")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("HP Universal Printing PS (v6.4.1)")
        }
        "Kyocera" {
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("Kyocera Classic Universaldriver KPDL")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("Kyocera Classic Universaldriver KPDL (A4 models)")
        }
        "Lexmark" {
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("Lexmark Universal v2 PS3")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("Lexmark Universal v2 PS3 (2.10.0.0)")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("Lexmark Universal v2 PS3 (2.11.0.0)")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("Lexmark Universal v2 PS3 (2.13.0.0)")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("Lexmark Universal v2 PS3 (2.14.0.0)")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("Lexmark Universal v2 PS3 (2.14.1.0)")
        }
        "Zebra" {
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner 110Xi4 203 dpi")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner ZDesigner 110Xi4 300 dpi")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner 220Xi4 300 dpi")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner GX430t")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner QLn420 (CPCL)")

            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner QLn420 (ZPL)")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner S4M-203dpi ZPL")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner ZD620-300dpi ZPL")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner ZM400 200 dpi (EPL)")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner ZM400 200 dpi (ZPL)")

            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner ZM400 300 dpi (ZPL)")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner ZM600 200 dpi (ZPL)")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner ZQ510 (ZPL)")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner ZQ630 (ZPL)")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner ZT230-200dpi ZPL")

            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner ZT410-300dpi ZPL")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner ZT420-300dpi ZPL")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner ZT610-300dpi ZPL")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner ZT610R-203dpi ZPL")
            $ComboDriver.Items.Add("ZDesigner ZT610R-300dpi ZPL")
        }
    }
    switch ($ComboModel.Text) {
        "Lexmark CX825dte" {
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("3")
        }
        "Lexmark CX921de" {
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("0")
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("1")
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("2")
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("3")
        }
        "Lexmark CX922de" {
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("0")
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("1")
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("2")
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("3")
        }
        "Lexmark MX910de" {
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("0")
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("1")
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("2")
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("3")
        }
        "Lexmark X950de" {
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("0")
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("1")
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("2")
            $ComboTray.Items.Add("3")
        }
    }
})
<# this part contains the variable assignment but not working
$maker = $ComboMaker.SelectedItem
$modelfull = $ComboModel.SelectedItem
$tray = $ComboTray.SelectedItem

$driver = $ComboDriver.SelectedItem

$TextBoxPQ = $window.FindName("TextBoxPQ")
$PQ = $TextBoxPQ.Text

$TextBoxServer = $window.FindName("TextBoxServer")
$server = $TextBoxServer.Text

$TextBoxHostname = $window.FindName("TextBoxHostname")
$hostname = $TextBoxHostname.Text

$TextBoxLocation = $window.FindName("TextBoxLocation")
$location = $TextBoxLocation.Text

#>

$ButtonRun = $window.FindName("ButtonRun")
$ButtonRun.Add_Click({
    # here variables are not working as well
    $maker = $ComboMaker.SelectedItem
    $modelfull = $ComboModel.SelectedItem
    $tray = $ComboTray.SelectedItem

    $driver = $ComboDriver.SelectedItem

    $TextBoxPQ = $window.FindName("TextBoxPQ")
    $PQ = $TextBoxPQ.Text

    $TextBoxServer = $window.FindName("TextBoxServer")
    $server = $TextBoxServer.Text

    $TextBoxHostname = $window.FindName("TextBoxHostname")
    $hostname = $TextBoxHostname.Text

    $TextBoxLocation = $window.FindName("TextBoxLocation")
    $location = $TextBoxLocation.Text

    if ($RadioCreate.Checked -eq $true){
        PortCreation
        PrinterCreation
        if ($maker -eq 'Lexmark') {
            ApplyConfigLexmark
        }
    }
    if ($RadioChange.Checked -eq $true) {
        ChangeDriver
        if ($maker -eq 'Lexmark') {
            ApplyConfigLexmark
        }
    }
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Operation completed!')

})
    
    #Show form

$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

#endregion
```

Also I would like to link the model selection to another variable called 'model' that will use a shortcut of the model to deploy some specific settings and once the Operation success mesasge' pops up and you press OK, all comboboxes and texboxes reset to blank.

FYI: PortCreation, PrinterCreation, ChangeDriver and ApplyConfigLexmark are functions that execute code in Powershell so I am not putting the whole code. Variables that I am using are below:

```
$maker # choose the brand of the physical device
$model # short name of the device model
$modelfull # Full device model
$tray # number of the trays the device has
$driver # Driver name
$PQ # print queue name
$server # hostname of the server
$hostname # hostname of the printer
$location # location of the device
```

Comment: Check my updated answer and let me know if helps or any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and changed this line to show the maker and it works. Why do you say the variable is not binding?

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Operation completed!' + $maker)
```

Also Checked should be IsChecked

```
if ($RadioCreate.IsChecked -eq $true){
```

Comment: Hi @Hassan , when I press the Run button, the program does not do anything, even does not start the process to create the the print queue. I've been struggling for a long while now and honestly I don't know what else I can do to make it work

Comment: Update. It is working but only the Creation part :) I will figure out why the other part is not workiing. Now I need to add more MessageBox to make it more interactive with the user. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Menistro Great, did my answer help?